# Network connection between windows 10 and windows XP

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-xp, lan

I have three laptops: lenovo A (win 10 home), lenovo B (win 10 home) and old HP nx6310 (win XP, SP3, PRO). 
I try to connect them together via ASUS RT-N12E, wifi router. I can connect to internet from each laptop. I can connect at least one way between win 10 systems. I can ping between all 3 laptops. But I cannot connect from win XP to win 10 and vice versa. I tried many things, so maybe something went wrong.
I use same IP XXX.YYY.ZZZ address for all laptops, I have same work group. I even see Win10 laptops from windows XP. (Or in previous restart I saw XP machine from windows 10). But when I click to (win 10) machine in workgroup it writes (I try to translate):

"Item \Laptop_with_win10 is not accessible. You have insufficient authorization for access to this item. Turn to your server administrator and check your permission.

Path in network was not found.
(OK)
"

(remark: windows 10 uses wifi, XP is on cable, but it can be change to wifi also.)

Have you got any suggestion or idea what to do?

remark2: I normally log in to XP and win 10 with administrator rights, and use widows account. One small thing happened with my experiments that XP log in with window form instead of whole screen with icons. I do not know how I did it.

Comment: Be sure to put account passwords on each computer before attempting this step.

The first next step is to create workgroups. In Windows XP, create a Workgroup X (give a meaningful name). Then do the same on Windows 10 (use the new settings panel and search for Workgroup). 

Once you do this, on XP go to the workgroup (My Network Places) and then on the left, click "Setup a home or small office network". Now once this complete, try accessing the Win. 10 computer from Win XP. This should work.

Comment: If I get you answer it did not work. I just simply changed name or workgroup and get the same error message as before.

I also thought you might mean "Network ID" button in "system properties" but it is shaded in my Windows home. Its equivalent in XP PRO probably only renamed workgroup name to "workgroup".

Maybe is something terribly wrong with my win XP.

Comment: Something to add. If there is any third party firewall/internet security, you will have to adjust the firewall's properties as well.

Answer (score 2):

Original problem still persists - I cannot connect from windows 10 to XP and vice versa. (I saw lots of different sites, for example editing Local security settings in windows XP, where I did not have a clue what I was doing, but it still did not help).

But there is very **easy workaround**. I saw this helpful video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-46uUTE5O98

I actually only needed from video: connect to win xp other way than through windows explorer.

1. Right click on start button -> click Run
2. Fill in IP of XP machine and desired shared folder. (obtained through ipconfig command on windows xp machine)

For example:

```
 \\192.163.2.38\my_shared_folder_on_windows_XP
```

3. fill in proper credentials (login and password) of the XP machine.
4. then "my_shared_folder_on_windows_XP" will show up in Network folder. This worked for XP machine IP by cable connection and windows 10 by wireless.

Wireless connection of win XP (and windows 10), though, produced the same fault as earlier:

"Windows cannot access \192.163.2.(wireless IP number)\my_shared_folder_on_windows_XP"

Error: 0x80070035

**Remark 1**

My windows 10 settings:

Firewall ON!

```
 \Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings


 ---Private (current profile)---
 Network discovery
       * Turn on...
         v Turn on...

 Filter and printer sharing
       * Turn on...

 HomeGroup connections
       *Allow...


 ---Guest or Public---
 Network discovery
        *Turn on...

 File and printer sharing
        *Turn on...


 ---All Network---
 Public folder sharing
        *Turn on...

 Media streaming

 File sharing connections
        *Enable file sharing for devices...

 Password protected sharing
        *Turn off...
```

windows XP: firewall ON!

**Remark 2**

this is not general solution to the error 80070035, as noob I suppose that error 80070035 can be caused by very different reasons.

**Remark 3**

Connection from windows XP to windows 10, works in similar fashion (you have to give security permissions on windows 10 shared folder). Though I mainly tested connection from windows 10.

Answer (score -4):

It's difference of Encryption level among OS'es.
You can change the in local security policy of win10 to support that of win XP.
Make sure proper credentials exists on the systems.

Comment: Well, I do not know what you mean exactly. I have Win10 Home, and have no "local security policy". But I have xp pro and have something like: "local security settings". But still I do not know what to do with it.

Comment: Please explain *how* to do this.